# How do I display Grouped Bar Chartfor multiple fields? (Altair)

Tags: python, plot, altair

I have the following dataset

[image]

I want to display this in some kind of diagram: the parameters should be located on the X-axis: confirmed, deaths, recovered. They must be defined for each region_name. The Y axis should be the sum of these values. I read about the melt () method in the official documentation, but I didn't quite understand how to use it.

I need to get something like this, only in the following form.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *wide-form* data; you need to convert it to *long-form* data. You can either do that in pandas using `melt()` or a similar method, or you can use Altair's `transform_fold`. You can read more about this in https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data

For your data, it might look something like this:

```python
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

data = pd.read_csv('data_from_screenshot.csv')

alt.Chart(data).transform_fold(
  ["confirmed", "deaths", "recovered"],
  as_=["field", "value"]
).mark_bar().encode(
  x="field:N",
  y="sum(value):Q",
  column="region_name:N"
)
```